# Locating syntax error in Drools

Tags: drools

I have a drool file where rule 2 is always coming out to true.

```
rule "R2"
salience 1000

when

((residence status = "US Citizen") || ((residence status = "Lawfully-entered Alien") and (residence duration >= 5))) and (fpl <= 133)
then

Add to Programs List "3"
end
```

the value of

```
residence status is US Citizen
residence status is null 
residence duration is 0
fpl is 278.77
```

Why it is going into it always though for specified value the condition is false .

Kindly find the all files.

```
package com.eligibility.service;  


import com.platform.enrollment.domain.BasicInfo;
import com.platform.enrollment.domain.FamilyMember;
global java.util.List prog_id_list; 
global java.lang.Double fpl;

[condition][] and=and 
[condition][] or=or

[condition][]residence status \= "{value}"=FamilyMember(basicInfo.citizenshipStatus == "{value}")
[condition][]residence duration >\= {value}=FamilyMember(basicInfo.permanentResidenceDuration >= {value})
[condition][]job status \= "{value}"=FamilyMember(basicInfo.jobStatus == "{value}")
[condition][]large business status \= "{value}"=FamilyMember(basicInfo.largeBusinessStatus == "{value}")
[condition][]false=eval(false)
[condition][]true=eval(true)
[condition][]age \= {value}=FamilyMember(basicInfo.getAge=={value})
[condition][]age < {value}=FamilyMember(basicInfo.getAge<{value})
[condition][]age > {value}=FamilyMember(basicInfo.getAge>{value})
[condition][]age <\= {value}=FamilyMember(basicInfo.getAge<={value})
[condition][]age >\= {value}=FamilyMember(basicInfo.getAge>={value})

[condition][]fpl \= {value}=eval(fpl=={value})
[condition][]fpl < {value}=eval(fpl<{value})
[condition][]fpl > {value}=eval(fpl>{value})
[condition][]fpl <\= {value}=eval(fpl<={value})
[condition][]fpl >\= {value}=eval(fpl>={value})

[condition][]gender \= "{value}"=FamilyMember(basicInfo.gender == "{value}")

[condition][]pregnant \= true=Applicant(eval(pregnant))
[condition][]pregnant \= false=Applicant(eval(!pregnant))

[condition][]Family member age greater than or equal to 60 \= true=eval(any_member_greater_than_equal_to_60)
[condition][]Family member age greater than or equal to 60 \= false=eval(!any_member_greater_than_equal_to_60)

[condition][]job status \= "{value}"=Applicant(eval(job_status.contains("{value}")))

[condition][]large business status \= "{value}"=Applicant(eval(large_business_status.contains("{value}")))
[condition][]employer benefits \= "{value}"=Applicant(eval(large_business_status.contains("{value}")))

[condition][]spouse \= true=eval(spouse)
[condition][]spouse \= false=eval(!spouse)

[condition][]total assets \= {value}=eval(total_assets=={value})
[condition][]total assets < {value}=eval(total_assets<{value})
[condition][]total assets > {value}=eval(total_assets>{value})
[condition][]total assets <\= {value}=eval(total_assets<={value})
[condition][]total assets >\= {value}=eval(total_assets>={value})

[condition][] Question with code "{code}" has answer "{answer}"=Question(code=="{code}"&& eval(answer.contains("{answer}")))

[consequence][]Add to Programs List {id}=prog_id_list.add({id});    

rule "R0"
salience 1000

when

(age <= 0) and ((residence status = "US Citizen") || (residence status = "Lawfully-entered Alien")) and (fpl <= 200)
then

Add to Programs List "1"
end

rule "R1"
salience 1000

when

((residence status = "US Citizen") || (residence status = "Lawfully-entered Alien")) and (fpl >= 400)
then

Add to Programs List "2"
end

rule "R2"
salience 1000

when

((residence status = "US Citizen") || ((residence status = "Lawfully-entered Alien") and (residence duration >= 5))) and (fpl <= 133)
then

Add to Programs List "3"
end

rule "R3"
salience 1000

when

((residence status = "US Citizen") || (residence status = "Lawfully-entered Alien")) and (fpl > 133) and (fpl < 400)
then

Add to Programs List "4"
end
```

Can anybody help me why it is enetring is list3 though data as provided above is not making it valid

Comment: Where is rule 3? It says `rule "R2"` in your file.

Comment: actually rule are numered as R0 , R1 ,R2 so R2 si rule three :)

Comment: dsl file entry for residence status is  [condition][]residence duration >\= {value}=FamilyMember(basicInfo.permanentResidenceDuration >= {value})

Comment: if i remove residence duration it starts working correctly.

Comment: one thing more value of basicInfo.permanentResidenceDuration is null

Comment: i got the issue now need help in writing dsl condition the basicInfo.permanentResidenceDuration is coming out to be null and doing comparison with 5 it giving error. Can any hep me out write dsl Condition Like this : if(basicInfo.permanentResidenceDuration == null){ initialize with 0 } else { initialize with value in basicInfo.permanentResidenceDuration }

Answer (score 0):

It could also be helpful to look at the generated java class for your rule and see what the issue might be.
Use:
-Ddrools.dump.dir=
to set path for the generated code.

It could also be helpful to set a rules listener and look at the fact insertions updates and rules firing sequence.

Also you could try to break the problematic rule into two rules without DSL as follows for debug purpose:

```
when
FamilyMember(basicInfo.citizenshipStatus == "US Citizen")
Fact(eval(fpl <= 133))

when
FamilyMember(basicInfo.citizenshipStatus == "Lawfully-entered Alien")
FamilyMember(basicInfo.permanentResidenceDuration >= 5)
Fact(eval(fpl <= 133))
```

Hope this helps.